# sf: Write Lat/Long from geometry into separate column and keep ID column

Tags: r, r-sf

I have a df with polygon ID's from a shapefile and their centre-points in a geometry column:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
     ID     geometry
  <dbl> <POINT [Â°]>
1     1 (117.2 31.8)
2     2 (116.4 40.1)
3     4   (117.9 26)
```

I want to put the latitude/longitude values into separate columns, so I do:

```
library(sf)
centres<- as.data.frame(st_coordinates(df))
```

This new 'centres' dataframe has the lat&long values, but misses the ID column.
How can I preserve it, or is there another way to get the lat&long values into separate columns from the geometry column whilst keeping the ID in the same df?

dput for the dataframe is:

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 4), 
      geometry = structure(list(structure(c(117.2, 31.8), 
      class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(116.4, 40.1), 
      class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(117.9, 26.0), 
      class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_POINT", "sfc"), 
      precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 116.4, ymin = 26.0, xmax = 117.9, ymax = 40.1), 
      class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(epsg = 4326L, 
      proj4string = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), 
      row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("sf", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
      sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(ID = NA_integer_), 
      class = "factor", .Label = c("constant", "aggregate", "identity")))
```

Comment: `cbind(df, st_coordinates(df))`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Solution using unlist + map()

```
library(tidyverse)

separated_coord <- df %>%
    mutate(long = unlist(map(df$geometry,1)),
           lat = unlist(map(df$geometry,2)))

separated_coord
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great

Comment: This works great. I think it should be a function that ships with `sf`, something like `add_coordinates()`.

Answer (score 55):

`st_coordinates` can be used with `dplyr::mutate`:

```r
library(magrittr) #for the pipe
df <- df %>%
  dplyr::mutate(lon = sf::st_coordinates(.)[,1],
                lat = sf::st_coordinates(.)[,2])

df
Simple feature collection with 3 features and 3 fields
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 116.4 ymin: 26 xmax: 117.9 ymax: 40.1
CRS:            EPSG:4326
# A tibble: 3 x 4
     ID     geometry   lon   lat
* <dbl>  <POINT [°]> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 (117.2 31.8)  117.  31.8
2     2 (116.4 40.1)  116.  40.1
3     4   (117.9 26)  118.  26
```

And if you no longer care about `geometry`, transform in a standard dataframe using `df %>% sf::st_set_geometry(NULL)` (even better, you can use `st_drop_geometry()` as mentioned in comments)

Comment: Great solution. Maybe flip the lon and lat labels though?

Comment: It appears this has been fixed since XY -> Lon / Lat.  And it was edited after Jordan's comment. ("two-dimensional points refer to x and y, easting and northing, or longitude and latitude, we refer to them as XY" https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/articles/sf1.html)

Comment: I use `st_drop_geometry()` instead of `sf::st_set_geometry(NULL)`.  Also, I think at the start of your answer you meant `st_coordinates` rather than `st_geometry`.  Otherwise, good answer.

Comment: With the new pipe `|>` : `df |> {\(.) mutate(., coords = sf::st_coordinates(.))}()`

Answer (score 9):

A possible approach is to unlist it.

```
setNames(data.frame(df[[1]], 
                    matrix(unlist(df[2]), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)), 
         c("ID", "lon", "lat"))

#   ID   lon  lat
# 1  1 117.2 31.8
# 2  2 116.4 40.1
# 3  4 117.9 26.0
```

***Explanation***

Data structure check with `str(df)` shows, that a variable - `geometry` - is in `list` format, which can be unhandy. A way to solve this is to `unlist()` it, transform it into a 2-column matrix, and reassemble it with the first column. With `setNames()` we are able to assign new column names in one step.

Comment: Thanks! Works great