# sf to data.frame: why as_Spatial needed before as.data.frame

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf, geom-text

Let's say I want to add labels to a geom_sf() plot, to get the following:

[image]

as of Nov/2020 the method does not exist, thus I get a warning and nothing gets plotted when I try:

```
library(sf)
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = nc, aes(label = CNTY_ID))

 Warning message:
 Ignoring unknown aesthetics: label
```

When trying to add labels manually, via **geom_text()**, I can't figure out how to go from **nc** to "nc2" which I can use in a ggplot:

If I try the following, output is not as expected:

```
nc2 <- nc %>% st_centroid() %>%        # ok, transform multypoligon to centroid
  as.data.frame()                      # does not return something useful, WHY ?
```

[image]

but if I do:

```
nc2 <- nc %>% st_centroid() %>%  
  as_Spatial() %>%                     # this is nonsense, why ?
  as.data.frame()
```

[image]

Now, using the following I can get the initially desired plot with proper labels.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = nc) +
  geom_text(data=nc2, aes(coords.x1, coords.x2, label=CNTY_ID))
```

What is the recommended way to **go from** *sf* **to** *tibble/data.frame* **to** ggplot?  Seems to me this is an ordinary task,  and having to go through two steps *(as_Spatial() + as.data.frame())* is wrong.

Comment: Have you tried geom_sf_label? https://yutannihilation.github.io/ggsflabel/reference/geom_sf_label.html

Comment: @mrhellmann Certainly tried it. Version 0.0.1 cannot be installed on my machine; (issue opened here: https://github.com/yutannihilation/ggsflabel/issues/3) but the question is really about going from **sf** to **tidy data** that can be plotted

Comment: If adding x & y coordinates to the sf object (in a non-list, non-geometry) column is what you're looking for this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61745776/7547327

Answer (score 3):

You can use `stat_sf_coordinates` with `geom = "text"` in ggplot. You don't even need to create a second data frame; you can pass `st_centroid` as a parameter.

The following is actually a full reprex that should work for anyone who has recent versions of ggplot2 and sf installed:

```r
ggplot2::ggplot(sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"))) +
  ggplot2::geom_sf() +
  ggplot2::stat_sf_coordinates(fun.geometry = sf::st_centroid,
                               ggplot2::aes(label = CNTY_ID), geom = "text")
```

[image]