# how to get the 'mean' point of the polygon's coordinates?

Tags: r, r-sp, rgdal

I have created a data frame (`projects`) by merging a shape file (US Zip codes) and a dataset. The below line of code returns the X and Y coordinates of my data frame. I would like to get the 'mean' point of the polygon's coordinates (lat and long) and add them to the `projects` data frame.
I tried `st_centroid()` but got an error:

> Error in wk_handle.wk_wkb(wkb, s2_geography_writer(oriented = oriented, : Loop 0 is not valid: Edge 1616 has duplicate vertex with edge 2124 –

```
#> head(st_coordinates(projects))
             X        Y L1 L2 L3
[1,] -71.36374 41.85854  1  1  1
[2,] -71.36449 41.85847  1  1  1
[3,] -71.36473 41.85844  1  1  1
[4,] -71.36580 41.85834  1  1  1
[5,] -71.36573 41.85828  1  1  1
[6,] -71.36562 41.85818  1  1  1
```

Comment: Generally one needs a [MCVE] to deal with errors.

Comment: Have you tried `sf::st_make_valid(`, prior to st_centroid, or in sp case, tested it with `rgeos::gisValid`?

Comment: sf::st_make_valid returns the geometry type of my data and some other info. However, I got an error after st_centroid: in wk_handle.wk_wkb(wkb, s2_geography_writer(oriented = oriented,  :

Comment: is `sp` tag intentional or should it read `sf` as the question suggests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this about a single centroid for your whole dataset or finding a centroid for each (multi)polygon? Provided data seems to hint former as it lists just coordinate pairs, though question states *polygons*.

Using dataset from `sf` package. First example starts with sf object of multipolygons, takes an union and from that finds a single centroid:

```r
library(sf)
nc = st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))

### centroid of multiploygons
head(nc[c("NAME", "geometry")])
#> Simple feature collection with 6 features and 1 field
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -81.74107 ymin: 36.07282 xmax: -75.77316 ymax: 36.58965
#> Geodetic CRS:  NAD27
#>          NAME                       geometry
#> 1        Ashe MULTIPOLYGON (((-81.47276 3...
#> 2   Alleghany MULTIPOLYGON (((-81.23989 3...
#> 3       Surry MULTIPOLYGON (((-80.45634 3...
#> 4   Currituck MULTIPOLYGON (((-76.00897 3...
#> 5 Northampton MULTIPOLYGON (((-77.21767 3...
#> 6    Hertford MULTIPOLYGON (((-76.74506 3...
c_multiploy <- st_union(nc) |> st_centroid()
c_multiploy
#> Geometry set for 1 feature 
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -79.40065 ymin: 35.55937 xmax: -79.40065 ymax: 35.55937
#> Geodetic CRS:  NAD27
#> POINT (-79.40065 35.55937)

# multiploygons (grey):
plot(nc$geometry, lwd = .15, border = "grey70", main = paste0("c_multiploy = ", c_multiploy))
# union of multiploygons (blue):
plot(st_union(nc), lwd = 2, border = "blue", add =TRUE)
# centroid of union (red):
plot(st_union(nc) |> st_centroid(), pch = 4, cex = 3, lwd = 5, col = "red", add =TRUE)
```

[image]

2nd example first generates centroids of mulitpolygons, so if this is what you are after, you can just stop there. Then finds a union (multipoint) to get a single centroid.

```r
### centroid of points:
nc_points <- st_centroid(nc)
head(nc_points[c("NAME", "geometry")])
#> Simple feature collection with 6 features and 1 field
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -81.49823 ymin: 36.36142 xmax: -76.02719 ymax: 36.49111
#> Geodetic CRS:  NAD27
#>          NAME                   geometry
#> 1        Ashe  POINT (-81.49823 36.4314)
#> 2   Alleghany POINT (-81.12513 36.49111)
#> 3       Surry POINT (-80.68573 36.41252)
#> 4   Currituck POINT (-76.02719 36.40714)
#> 5 Northampton POINT (-77.41046 36.42236)
#> 6    Hertford POINT (-76.99472 36.36142)
c_points <- st_union(nc_points) |> st_centroid()
c_points
#> Geometry set for 1 feature 
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -79.5111 ymin: 35.64247 xmax: -79.5111 ymax: 35.64247
#> Geodetic CRS:  NAD27
#> POINT (-79.5111 35.64247)

# points (grey):
plot(nc_points$geometry, pch = 1, cex = 3, col = "grey70", main = paste0("c_points = ", c_points))
# union of points (blue):
plot(st_union(nc_points), pch = 3, cex = 1, col = "blue", add = TRUE)
# centroid of union (red):
plot(st_union(nc_points) |> st_centroid(), pch = 4, cex = 3, lwd = 5, add =TRUE, col = "red")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your suggested solutions! The 2nd example should work for me but I got an error after running nc_points <- st_centroid(projects) Error in wk_handle.wk_wkb(wkb, s2_geography_writer(oriented = oriented,  : 
  Loop 0 is not valid: Edge 1616 has duplicate vertex with edge 2124

Comment: What's the CRS of your sf object? What if you first switch off s2 with `sf_use_s2(FALSE)` ?

Comment: Would appreciate a comment of why it still worked for you so I can update the answer. S2? Switched to projected CRS?

Comment: Yes! Switching worked!